# Rails s will hang on any request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

For a rails 6.0.3.5 API, when running `rails s` this is the output I get:

```sh
    rails s
    /home/fito/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 6.0.3.5 application starting in development 
    => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
    * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    * Environment: development
    * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And, after sending any query, it just hangs without any additional output to the terminal or to the development.log file:

For example, when sending simple GET queries to the localhost:3000 address:

```sh
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2022-03-01 10:52:35 -0500
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2022-03-01 10:52:56 -0500
```

A new log line appears after sending any request, but no additional lines are printed to the output or to the log files and I really don't know how to debug the issue because of this. I already tried adding this line to the development.rb file:

```rb
  config.eager_load = true
```

That did not fix the hanging.

I will provide any additional info needed.

Comment: Define "nothing happens". What are you *expecting* to see? Is there a response?

Comment: No additional output is shown and no response is sent.

Comment: What is the response *supposed* to be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very simple: I was executing a VPN software. I just had to turn it off and resetting by back-end.